# Convert varchar2 string to date - Oracle SQL Developer

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

Need to covert VARCHAR2 string in format of 20150101, 20150102, 20150125.....etc into date in format of 01/01/2015, 01/02/2015.... etc.

AND update TABLE DATA

ORACLE11G MY SQL DEVELOPER

ALL HELP APPRECIATED!!! LIFE SAVER
COMPLETE SQL PL/SQL NOOB!

Answer (score 2):

Just use `to_date()` that is what it is there for:

```
select to_date(col, 'YYYYMMDD')
```

If you then want to format this, you can use `to_char()`:

```
select to_char(to_date(col, 'YYYYMMDD'), 'DD/MM/YYYY')
```